# Redirect by user's radio input

Tags: jquery, redirect

I want to redirect page by user's radio input. Users can pick either "Large cities" or "Small cities", then they click a submit button and it should redirect them to the specific page.

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
    if($('input[name=city_type]:"big_cities"'){
        window.location.href="math_generator.php";
    })
});
```

This, however, isn't working

Comment: Should add your HTML to your post as well.

Comment: Define "isn't working" please. Are you getting errors? Post a [mcve] please

Answer (score 0):

Your current question does not have any of the PHP and HTML code and is missing most of the JS. 
Best solution I can think of is adding your variable as a get var at the end of the URL,

```
window.location.href="math_generator.php#city-type=value";
```

And in your php use $_GET["city-type"] to access the value.